# Print all xml child node using python

Tags: python, xml-parsing, elementtree, minidom

I want to print all the values of the "ClCompiler" child of "ItemGroup" of my xml file.

### my python code

```
tree = minidom.parse(project_path)
itemgroup = tree.getElementsByTagName('ItemGroup')
print (itemgroup[0].toxml())
```

### my result

```
<ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
        <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
        <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
        <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
        <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
</ItemGroup>
<ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="../../avmedia/source/framework/MediaControlBase.cxx"/>
    <ClCompile Include="../../avmedia/source/framework/mediacontrol.cxx"/>
    <ClCompile Include="../../avmedia/source/framework/mediaitem.cxx"/>
    <ClCompile Include="../../avmedia/source/framework/mediamisc.cxx"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

ecc

---

### expected result

```
    <ClCompile Include="../../basic/source/basmgr/basmgr.cxx"/>         
    <ClCompile Include="../../basic/source/basmgr/vbahelper.cxx"/>      
    <ClCompile Include="../../basic/source/classes/codecompletecache.cxx"/>
```

ecc

---

### part of my xml

```
<ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="../../basic/source/basmgr/basicmanagerrepository.cxx"/>
    <ClCompile Include="../../basic/source/basmgr/basmgr.cxx"/>
    <ClCompile Include="../../basic/source/basmgr/vbahelper.cxx"/>
    <ClCompile Include="../../basic/source/classes/codecompletecache.cxx"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made it half way.
You found all the *ItemGroup* nodes in the document. Now, you have to iterate through each of them and find its *ClCompile* children (most likely only one of them will have such children).

Here's the code:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

project_path = "./a.vcxproj"
item_group_tag = "ItemGroup"
cl_compile_tag = "ClCompile"


def main():
    tree = minidom.parse(project_path)
    item_group_nodes = tree.getElementsByTagName(item_group_tag)
    for idx, item_group_node in enumerate(item_group_nodes):
        print("{} {} ------------------".format(item_group_tag, idx))
        cl_compile_nodes = item_group_node.getElementsByTagName(cl_compile_tag)
        for cl_compile_node in cl_compile_nodes:
            print("\t{}".format(cl_compile_node.toxml()))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

**Notes**:

- I ran the code with *Python 3.4* (since no version was mentioned in the question). *2.7* compatibility will require some minor changes.
- I did my tests on a *VStudio* project where the second search tag was *ClInclude*, but I guess that's an fairly old version.
- The 1<sup>st</sup> `print` line is only for illustrating the parent *ItemGroup* node. Comment it out to achieve your desired output.
- Needless to say that you should modify `project_path` to point to your project file.

Answer (score 2):

An alternate solution using ElementTree,

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
root = ET.fromstring('''\
<ItemGroup>
<ClCompile Include="../../avmedia/source/framework/MediaControlBase.cxx"/>
<ClCompile Include="../../avmedia/source/framework/mediacontrol.cxx"/>
<ClCompile Include="../../avmedia/source/framework/mediaitem.cxx"/>
<ClCompile Include="../../avmedia/source/framework/mediamisc.cxx"/>
</ItemGroup>
''')

for child in root.iter('ClCompile'):
    print(ET.tostring(child))
```

While parsing from file,

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree=ET.parse('text.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
for child in root.iter('ClCompile'):
    print(ET.tostring(child))
```